# How do I compute this integral using the Fubini and/or Tonelli theorem?

Tags: integration, fubini-tonelli-theorems

I have the following problem:

> Using Fubini and/or Tonelli theorems, compute the Lebesgue integral: $$\int_{[0,1]} \left(\int_{[y,1]} x^{-\frac{3}{2}} \cos\left(\frac{\pi y}{2x}\right) \,\,d\lambda(x)\right)d\lambda(y)$$

I wanted to do this in the following way:

Let us remark that we integrate over $$C=\{(x,y)|0\leq y\leq 1,\,\,\,y\leq x\leq 1\}=\{(x,y)|0\leq x\leq 1,\,\,\,0\leq y\leq x\}$$
Therefore under some condition (*) $$\int_{[0,1]} \left(\int_{[y,1]} x^{-\frac{3}{2}} \cos\left(\frac{\pi y}{2x}\right) \,\,d\lambda(x)\right)d\lambda(y)=\int_{[0,1]} \left(\int_{[0,x]} x^{-\frac{3}{2}} \cos\left(\frac{\pi y}{2x}\right) \,\,d\lambda(y)\right)d\lambda(x)=...=\frac{4}{\pi}$$

Now I only need to verify (*). I.e. I want to check if we can use Tonelli theorem. We consider $$f:[0,1]\times [0,x] \rightarrow \mathbb{R};\,\,(x,y)\mapsto x^{-\frac{3}{2}} \cos\left(\frac{\pi y}{2x}\right) $$ And remark that $x^{-\frac{3}{2}}\geq 0$ for all $x\in [0,1]$ and also $\cos\left(\frac{\pi y}{2x}\right)\geq 0$ for all $y\in [0,x]$. Now we also remark that f is mesurable, therefore we can apply Tonelli and we are finished.

Does this work like this?

Thank you for your help!